How to strike unchecked radio buttons' label only when there is one checked radio button?
So we have this HTML:
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="a" name="a"><label for="a">aaaa</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b" name="a"><label for="b">bbbb</label>
  <input type="radio" id="c" name="a"><label for="c">cccc</label>
  <input type="radio" id="d" name="a"><label for="d">dddd</label>
</div>

Nothing is checked, so no label is struck. Perfect. If I clicked on a label nothing yet happens. Let's change that with a bit of CSS:
input:not(:checked) + label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

Like this we have the right logic. Alas, the default case is not right. When nothing is checked, all labels are struck! How to change that? Is this possible in CSS only?
I try something cheesy and it went halfway. I can strike every label after. How to the firsts?
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+input+label,
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+input+label+input+label,
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+input+label+input+label+input+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

DEMO


input[type="radio"]:checked+label+input+label,
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+input+label+input+label,
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+input+label+input+label+input+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="a" name="a"><label for="a">aaaa</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b" name="a"><label for="b">bbbb</label>
  <input type="radio" id="c" name="a"><label for="c">cccc</label>
  <input type="radio" id="d" name="a"><label for="d">dddd</label>
</div>



Related but not a duplicate of CSS selector for a checked radio button's label

You can do it with the pseudo-class :has(). Here is the mdn entry about it.
div:has(> input[type="radio"]:checked)
> input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)
+ label {}

Or in plain english : we are looking to select a label just next to a radio button who's parent is a div who has at least one radio button child which is checked.
A shorter version but with the exact same logic inspired by G-Cyrillus is:
div:has(:checked) :not(:checked) + label

Demo:


div:has(> input[type="radio"]:checked) > input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label { text-decoration: line-through; }
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="a" name="a"><label for="a">aaaa</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b" name="a"><label for="b">bbbb</label>
  <input type="radio" id="c" name="a"><label for="c">cccc</label>
  <input type="radio" id="d" name="a"><label for="d">dddd</label>
</div>




You may combine :has() and :not() + selectors


div:has(input:checked) :not(input:checked) + label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="a" name="a"><label for="a">aaaa</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b" name="a"><label for="b">bbbb</label>
  <input type="radio" id="c" name="a"><label for="c">cccc</label>
  <input type="radio" id="d" name="a"><label for="d">dddd</label>
</div>




Well upvote because it is shorter but this is the same logic than mine, isn't it?

@aloisdg , oups, that's what happens when you start something, go somewhere and come back later and realize you did not submit :) . For the logic, yes but there is no other, it just answser the question. put a line through a label if not behind a checked input and if there's at list one sibbling input : checked ;)  I'll delete this duplicate answser later by the time you read this comment :)

no problem! Your answer still make me improve mine :)
